# Don't show jobs sidebar to people who have job-seeking status set to "not looking"

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not looking for a job.  I've set that in my Jobs preferences, and it's also the very first thing it says on my main profile, in all capital letters yet, and *still* I get junk job offers from recruiters who say they found me on here.  (I don't believe this is Stack Exchange's fault, to be clear.  I know you know that's not cool.)

Anyway, since I am not looking for a job, I am never ever ever going to click on the jobs sidebar, and I'd kinda like it not to be there at all, it gets in the way of browsing the list of wacky network questions.

Can you make that happen, please?  Don't display the jobs sidebar to people who set their Jobs preference to "not looking."

Comment: best you can do is adblock it. Even though jobs/careers are off topic for SO, they're going to continue showing it to us.

Comment: @Catija yes it is, OP talk about the job ads which appear in the sidebar. They appear in all SE sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Without an image to clarify, I don't know that we can be sure. I don't know what jobs ad you're talking about. When I'm on SO, I do see a big jobs info box on the right which I don't see anywhere else on the network (that I use). The "We have 13 open jobs" box is definitely not something I see.

Comment: @Catija hmm... yeah there's only the general Jobs ad, not specific companies. Well, so this is indeed specific to SO then.

Comment: If there is more than one thing that might be understood to be a "jobs sidebar" then I want to be able to hide ALL of them.

Comment: I don't actually even see what @ShadowWizard is talking about... but I use ABP... so it may be blocked by that. I definitely do see the big color changing box/es, though, and I see the general Community Promotion Ad spots.

Comment: That's their biggest income. Do you think they will implement this?

Comment: @Catija I'm talking about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y23gh.png) (taken in arqade for example), OP means [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbTNE.png) which appears only on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShadowWizard In fact, I mean _both_ of those, and anything else that could conceivably be understood as a job ad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback.

We'd prefer to show you only relevant ads, regardless of whether they relate to jobs.  As you point out, we have some work to do in this area.  For example, job ads do not currently account for your stated [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current), including whether your status is "not looking."

Unfortunately, I don't have a timeframe for when job ads might become more targeted (as targeting relates to explicitly-stated job preferences), nor do I know whether or how your request will be implemented.  If we do implement something like you are requesting, we will also want some means of encouraging users to update their job status.

Because you mentioned that recruiters have been contacting you, I double-checked whether any recruiters seemed to be sending you messages *through* Stack Overflow.  It doesn't look like it, at least not at all recently.  If they were, we would consider it a serious bug because you should not be appearing in an employer-user's candidate-search results at all if your status is "not looking" (which it is), and those users should likewise be unable to contact you through Stack Overflow.  If that has not been your experience, please let us know so we can fix it.

Comment: Thanks.  To be clear, the junk recruiter messages I was complaining about are direct emails (my email is not hard to find from my personal website), claiming (incorrectly) to have a job that's a good fit for me according to my main Stack Overflow profile. I don't think there's anything you can or should do about that, I just threw it in there to illustrate how very tired I am of job ads from _any_ source.

Answer (score -1):

This is internal advertisement of Stack Overflow, they're not going to turn it off.

This is not intrusive, rather small sized, and usually looking nice. I see no reason to remove it.

If you don't want a new job, simply ignore it, same way you probably ignore most advertisements in other sites.

Comment: I do not find this response helpful. Are you authorized to speak for the company? Whether or not you are, why did you feel the need to tell me to go jump in a lake?

Comment: @zwol There's nothing about meta that requires answers only come from people who are "authorized to speak for the company". Considering that jobs is one of the major monetizations that Stack Overflow Inc has, while I would hope that they would consider your request, I agree that it is unlikely because turning off the ads for anyone saying "not looking" (which doesn't get confirmed in any way) would be a massive loss of eyeballs on their ads, and make them less effective and less valuable.

Comment: @zwol adding to the other comment, if you want only official responses from Stack Overflow team, use the contact form instead of posting on the meta site.

Comment: I don't see why they'd have any problem with this, save on a technical difficulty-of-implementation level. If you are truly not looking for a job, then showing you jobs ads is not likely to be a money-maker for SO, Inc. It's the same logic for why they don't care if you block their ads entirely. Targeted advertising is always better, and if users are *telling* you how they want ads to be targeted to them, then it pays to listen.